# Orientation not working in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, orientation

I made an iPad application in which I want to support orientation, so I've written this code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
      //return YES;
    return (interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft||interfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I've created a few tables in portrait mode, so when I rotate my app, the tables still comes according to portrait mode only, but the table inside my view doesn't autoresize.

Comment: you need to document a little more your question. Like are you using a UIViewController inside of a UIViewController? That could cause problem with orientation.

Comment: i am using only navigation controller and only one view controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the table view itself is set to expand and contract in both directions when autoresized - this is easiest set in IB by clicking on the table view, then clicking on the ruler sidebar header tab, then making sure that all of the autoresizing options are turned on - resizes both directions, sticks to all corners.

Comment: i am creating table view programmatically so there is nothing in xib file, if you can provide me code snippet that will be helpful

Comment: Just look over the docs for the autoresizing behaviors of UIViews.  I do not do any UI component setups in code anymore as I feel it is a waste of time, so I have no example code to share.